# Any way to get rid of automated column snake case renaming in GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm planning to use GORM with an existing database, therefore I'm creating some models for it. However, I've got one problem - GORM automatically renames all column to lower snake case. I don't really need it, because the database I work with doesn't really use such names. I've found out, that I can use tag

```
`gorm:"column_name:`
```

In order to prevent my columns from being renamed. However, it doesn't really seem to be a viable solution for me, because I have a bunch of models with tons of columns. Is there any way to switch off this "renaming" policy from GORM, or to automatically add a tag to all of my models?

My models look like that:

```
type FOOD_DES struct {
NDB_NO string `gorm:"primary_key"`
FdGrp_Cd FD_GROUP
Long_Desc string
Shrt_Desc string
ComName string
ManufacName string
Survey string
Ref_desc string
Refuse float32
SciName string
N_Factor float32
Pro_Factor float32
Fat_Factor float32
CHO_Factor float32
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [doc](https://v2.gorm.io/docs/gorm_config.html#NamingStrategy):

> GORM allows users to change the naming conventions by overriding the
> default NamingStrategy which need to implements interface Namer
>
> ```
> type Namer interface {
>   TableName(table string) string
>   ColumnName(table, column string) string
>   JoinTableName(table string) string
>   RelationshipFKName(Relationship) string
>   CheckerName(table, column string) string
>   IndexName(table, column string) string
> }
> ```

So just implement interface Namer.

And in the old version, you can do like ([Ref](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/pull/2040))

```
gorm.AddNamingStrategy(&gorm.NamingStrategy{
    DB: func(name string) string {
        return name
    },
    Table: func(name string) string {
        return name
    },
    Column: func(name string) string {
        return name
    },
})
```